# Reading multiple txt files and saving them into one numpy array: how to concatenate numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

a) Here's my try. It works but I'm wondering if I can do it without if else conditions and indexing - more pythonic way.

```
sensor_files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']

for idx,sensor_file in enumerate(sensor_files):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        clean_lines = (line.replace(b';',b',') 
        sensors = np.genfromtxt(clean_lines, dtype=int, delimiter=',')
        if idx == 0: 
            acc_measurements = sensors
        else:
            acc_measurements = np.concatenate((acc_measurements, sensors))
```

Comment: are you allowed to use external libraries? `pandas` handles this stuff very well.

Comment: Of course. Can you post the solution, please?

Comment: Why the `replace`? can't you just use `delimiter=';'`?  What's the shape of `sensors` (after for both files)?  Unless there's something funny about the files, `genfromtxt` should be able to read them just as well as `pandas`.

Comment: @hpaulj Because I have both delimiters ',' and ';'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list append version:

```
alist = []
for sensor_file in sensor_files:
    with open(sensor_file, 'rb') as f:
        clean_lines = (line.replace(b';',b',') 
        sensors = np.genfromtxt(clean_lines, dtype=int, delimiter=',')
        alist.append(sensors)
acc_measurements = np.concatenate(alist)
```

`genfromtxt` does something similar.  It iterates on file lines, parses each and appends it to a list.  Then at the end it converts that list of lists into an array with the correct dtype.

Each `concatenate` creates a new array, copying data from the arguments.  List append operates 'in-place' adding just a pointer to the new `source`.  Lists are designed for fast appends.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the easiest solution - I could do it also on my own. Any difference between last 2 lines `alist.extend(sensors); acc_measurements = np.array(alist)` and your version?

Comment: I wouldn't use `extend`.  It splits up `sensors` along the first dimension.  So if `sensors` is 2d, the list will be a list of 1d arrays.  You'd have to use `vstack` of `stack` to join them instead of `concatenate`.  But go ahead and experiment (with a small samples).

Answer (score 1):

You may create an empty array with required columns and then in cycle use [numpy.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

Like:

```
 arr = numpy.array([[]]*5)   ## real length of sensors
 for idx,sensor_file in enumerate(sensor_files):
     ....
     arr = numpy.vstack((arr, sensors))
```

Comment: I tried with: `a =np.array([[]]*20)` then  `np.vstack((a, np.ones((20,0)), ))` output: `array([], shape=(40, 0), dtype=float64)`   so they got stacked well.

Comment: please don't iterate on `vstack`.  Append to a list instead, and turn the list into an array at the end.  It's simpler and faster.

Comment: But what to do if files are big? `np.array` will be more compact than lists

Answer (score 1):

A neat solution using pandas would be

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv")
df_concatenated = df1.append(df2)
```